# Unable to use the wifi

Tags: wireless, hp, dv6

I can't use wifi on my dv6-7044TX.  When I use rfkill list all its says the wifi connector is hard blocked. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Hard block usually refers to the switch on the laptop being turned off.

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows? if you are, boot Windows, enable wifi and reboot. In my system, if I disable wifi in Windows, I'm not able to unblock it in Ubuntu. Ubuntu is able to remove the soft block but not the hard block on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In Ubuntu

```
rfkill unblock all
```

If this doesn't work read on.

## If you are dual-booting with Windows.

Boot Windows, enable wifi and reboot.
In my system, if I disable wifi in Windows, I'm not able to unblock it in Ubuntu. Ubuntu is able to remove the soft block but not the hard block on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Hard block beans there is a button that turns WiFi on/off, and it's in `off` position.

If this is a laptop, check your function keys. On my laptop it's `F2`. You might need to hold `fn` key.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to switch on both my wifi and bluetooth in windows tobise wifi in ubuntu. For some weird reason when I disable bluetooth in ubuntu my wifi gets disabled as well